# Google map Geocoding Service using Ajax is not working with IE

Tags: javascript, google-maps, jquery

I am trying to make Ajax requests to the Google map Geocoding Service to get latitude and longitude, it does not work in IE but works perfectly in chrome and Firefox. Here is my Ajax snippet.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&sensor=false",
    type: 'get',
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(result){
       alert(result);
    }
});
```

What is going wrong.

Comment: Which IE version?iE9?

Comment: Version IE 9 and I want it to work with IE 8 also.

Comment: Are you allowed to use Google's Geocoder API?

Comment: @AlvinArulselvan its working in and Firefox that means   Google's Geocoder API is allowing my request.

Comment: Not true for some cases...take a look here..it might help...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17045025/how-do-cross-domain-requests-work-in-ie8